# Indexing by label with rows and columns at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get values of two or more different column in form of tuple

```
def top():
    Top15 = answer_one()
    x = Top15.loc[Top15['% Renewable'].idxmax()]
    return x.loc['% Renewable' , 'Country']
```

I want to get values of column named % Renewable and Country in form of a tuple

Comment: @: Aditya, Welcome to SO site, However, the best practice to get answer is to show the Dataset or Dataframe you have or few line of data at least to reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

[`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) supports indexing by row and column labels simultaneously:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})

res = tuple(df.loc[df['A'].idxmax(), ['A', 'B']])    # (2, 4)
```

Or if `list` is sufficient:

```
res = df.loc[df['A'].idxmax(), ['A', 'B']].tolist()  # [2, 4]
```

Comment: Good  example set @jpp.

Comment: After using the 'list' I am getting output [nan, 69.64803] although the name of country is available

Comment: @Aditya, Sorry, can't help further without a [mcve].

Comment: how can i upload my dataset

Comment: @Aditya, [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)